# Why DSCP always 0x00 (default) on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, qos

I send (TOS/DSCP 12 for audio and 10 for control) packets, and trace them on Wireshark, but all I see is 0x00 on DSCP field, always. Why is that?

I already tried to set the "DisableUserTOSSetting" field on registry to zero, didn't help.

Any other ideas??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A Google search revealed multiple people asking the same question with wording almost identical to yours. - Perhaps spend a bit more time searching the issue yourself?

[SEE HERE](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/1188/why-is-dscp-always-0-on-windows-7) on the Wireshark site, I'd use the below REGEDIT first, if this doesn't work I found multiple other suggestions by searching.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\QoS]
"Do not use NLA"="1"
```