# Application cannot successfully change dscp value on win7

Tags: java, windows-7, ip, windows-xp, qos

These questions are quite similar to mine :

[Why DSCP always 0x00 (default) on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247017/why-dscp-always-0x00-default-on-windows-7)

[Issue with DSCP marking using setTrafficClass and WireShark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260778/issue-with-dscp-marking-using-settrafficclass-and-wireshark)

I try to send packets with a custom dscp. I can't use MS QoS policies as the user should be able to change the value of the DSCP field. I use java and the method setTrafficClass (Socket obj).

I tried several things :

- In the Group Policy Editor > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings : right click on policy-based QOS > I have ticked "Control DSCP marking requests from applications and services" with "Allow"
- Add these two keys :
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters]
  "DisableUserTOSSetting"=dword:00000000 and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\QoS]
  "Do not use NLA"="1"

But the DSCP field desperatly stay at 0x00 (default), checked with wireshark 1.12.3

The most frustrating : I tried the same with windows XP : it works!

Here are the links I found useful so far :

http://www.pingman.com/kb/article/setting-dscp-qos-byte-on-packets-with-windows-7-8-95.html

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/1188/why-is-dscp-always-0-on-windows-7

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd919203%28WS.10%29.aspx

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link from MS web site:

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2733528

Policy based QoS not working in Windows 7 clients

it provides the answer for the case when you want to change policy based qos settings, but you are still seeing DSCP values equal to 0.
If you need to make DSCP values to take effect on the adapter which does not have Domain access, you need to add the following registry on the system:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\QoS

Type: REG_SZ 
Name: Do not use NLA 
Value: 1

Create key "QoS" if it does not exist.

After you create the above registry key, you need to reboot the computer.

hth